# Missing JsonUtil in WSO2EI 7.x

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2EI 7.0 with  WSO2 developer Studio 7.0.2. I was trying to implement the following code for setting the payload in a WSO2 custom mediator.

```java
String jsonPayloadToString = JsonUtil.jsonPayloadToString(((Axis2MessageContext) messageContext).getAxis2MessageContext()); 
System.out.println("Payload in string -"+ jsonPayloadToString);
```

But I am unable to import the `JsonUtil` class in Maven generated code.

Can I know if I need to set the class path or jar manually to import this package?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the following imports?

```
import org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil;
import org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2MessageContext;
```

Also, you need to have the corresponding synapse version in the pom file under dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.synapse</groupId>
        <artifactId>synapse-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7-wso2v105</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Yes ,  I try to  import . But cant see 'org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil' . Try to import this , gives error . In package hierarchy i am unable to see this class(JsonUtil) file .

Comment: I tried debug the issue , it was an bug in WSO2 developer  studio 7.x .  it was importing while executing with maven outside studio .

Comment: Can you please report this bug in https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues

Comment: Hi @Nand_Dev,

Did you found any solution for this? i am facing the issue in WSO2 Developer Studio

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue, But resolved above JsonUtil ERROR by adding below dependency in pom.xml

**Note**: after updating pom.xml, please do mvn update by clicking alt+f5.

dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.synapse/synapse-commons -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.synapse</groupId>
    <artifactId>synapse-commons</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7-wso2v228</version>
</dependency>
```

Reference Link: [dependency ref](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.synapse/synapse-commons?repo=wso2-releases)